# Amzon web services: How to access a MySQL RDS within a EC2 instance with default VPC

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rds

I recently created an EC2 instance within Amazon hosting. I also have a MySQL RDS instance that I want to use with the deployment (MVC and EF with .net connector). I am using default VPC. I am able to access the RDS with my local MYSQL workbench on the endpoint xxx.xxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306 since I added for inbound and outbound rules to the security group:
MYSQL TCP 3306 0.0.0.0/0
All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0

However, my deployment is not able to access the RDS instance with the same endpoint. I am getting error:

```
          System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider     failed on Open. 
---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found
       at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean includeIPv6)
       at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(String hostNameOrAddress)
       at MySql.Data.Common.MyNetworkStream.CreateStream(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings, Boolean unix)
       at MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetTcpStream(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection()
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
```

I did install the .Net connector on the EC2. I don't understand why my local MySQL can connect to the remote RDS but an EC2 running in the same VPC and security group can not. Help would really be appreciated , thanks.

UPDATE:
It seems that the EC2 has no internet access. When I ping google.com, it says ping can not find host google.com. The EC2 instance does have an elastic IP.

Answer (score 2):

You have to configure an internet gateway in your VPC and enable 0.0.0.0 traffic in your routing table to the internet gateway to allow internet access from your EC2 instance. [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html)

for example:

[image]